# When press Back Button, to send a value previous Activity

Tags: android

Hi everyone I want to this: When press Action bar Back Button, to send a value previous Activity. And check value stay there.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                //i'm giving error because i mustnt create new activity i must to send previous activity..
                LoginActivity yeni=new LoginActivity();
                yeni.setPassword("");
                this.finish();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

When I press the back button sign out the application and go loginscreen but I must change a value in loginactivity because if I don't login activity again login same values and start main activity...

Clearly, When I pressed the back button I must send a value maybe null to a method in `LoginActivity`. Like this:

```
   public void setPassword(String comingpass)
    {
        _passwordText.setText(comingpass);

    }
```

When it knows `_passwordtext=null` stay there and wait for new login...

Comment: use startActivityForResult for data pass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// call activity with startActivityForResult
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);


//back press
switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
 Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("flag",1);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


//handle back in main activity
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

if (requestCode == 1) {
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if(data.getIntExtra("flag",0)==1){
        yeni.setPassword("");
    }
    }
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        //Write your code if there's no result
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you , good answer , but you can edit here data.getIntExtra("flag") taking two arguments a default value data.getIntExtra("flag",0) can be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Use `startActivityForResult()`.  [Getting a Result from an Activity | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
 in Activity B:

    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", strtext + "");
    setResult(2, intent);


            super.onBackPressed();
 }

in Activity A:
       Intent itemintent = new Intent(contextt, ActivityB.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("mflag", 0);
                itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);
                startActivityForResult(itemintent, 2);

       @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String sSuName = data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
       // txtfavouratecount.setText(sSuName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```