# Can I go back to a previous activity (with saved data) without using startActivityForResult()?

Tags: android-studio

For context, I have 3 different activities. The first has an EditText where the user can enter a player's username and a Button that will take the user to the SecondMainActivity. On the SecondMainActivity, I made to where that activity has a variable that stores the string for what the user entered. Finally, there are some ImageViews where if the user clicks on them, they will be taken to the ThirdMainActivity that displays information about the user. Additionally, the variable from the SecondMainActivity will transfer that string to a new variable in the ThirdMainActivity. Note: I'm using Intents to transfer the string to the new activities.

Now, I know that when I use android:parentActivityName=".SecondMainActivity", an arrow will appear on the top left corner where it'll take me back to the SecondMainActivity. The problem with this is that it launches a brand new SecondMainActivity that doesn't retrieve the string that was entered in the EditText from the first (Main) Activity. This causes an error in my code because when I click on the ImageViews, I get an error that there is no string value in the ThirdActivity.

I've researched for a possible solution to this and found about startActivityForResult(). However, the problem with this (for me) is I believe I need to include some sort of Button or an onClickListener to send back the string to the SecondMainActivity. I don't want to include a Button on my ThirdMainActivity and instead keep the back button feature for going back to a previous activity.

I was thinking that there was some additionally method I could include in the AndroidManifest file for the activity to send back the data, but I'm not sure of anything else.

To summarize, what can I add so I can use the "back button" feature on Android Studio to go back to the SecondMainActivity with the stored string? This activity would be the same activity that would keep the input from the FirstActivity and not a new one.

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38933023/when-press-back-button-to-send-a-value-previous-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your edittext entered text and ImageViews set drawable to your in local memory SharedPreferences ,
And after it set the store values to your nextAvtivitys edittext and ImageViews .
and when you go back set Similar your privous Store SharedPreferences to all of your edittext and ImageViews.

```
//set your SharedPreferences 
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MySharedPref",MODE_PRIVATE);

//get your edittext
String name=youredittext..getText().toString();

//store text
SharedPreferences.Editor myEdit = sharedPreferences.edit();
myEdit.putString("firstname",name);
myEdit.commit();

//get string back 
 String getname=sharedPreferences.getString("firstname", "defaultname");
//set store text to your next activity  edittext
edittext.setText(String.valueOf(getname));
```

Hope its work